# How to move all comment replies under the ones replied to on my Blogspot blog?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [location of the comments](http://income-control.blogspot.com/2011/09/this-is-last-post.html#comments) I need help with on my scrap Blogger/blogspot blog.

I'm trying to move the replies under the ones they reply to.

1. I want to move the reply starting from the `<li>` node it is in, then
2. place it in a created `<ul class="children">` tag inside of the `<li>` node of which the comment replies to
3. I also want to remove the reply from the moved comment(s)

The comments look like this:

```
<li class="comments">...</li>
<li class="comments">...</li>
<li class="comments">...</li>
```

When the comment is moved, it should look like:

```
<li class="comment">

<div class="comment-body>...</div>

<ul class="children"> /* Inserted via javascript */

  <li class="comment">...</li> /* This is the moved comment */

</ul>

</li>

<li class="comment">...</li>
```

If you are using Firebug, you can see the threaded look I'm looking for by moving an `<li class="comment">` inside of another.

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, you could use the `::first-child` pseudo selector to move the first comment or parent comment to the left. You can do this by applying a margin to all the comments except for the `first-child` one.

**Update:**

**How to use JQuery for this.**

1. Get the [contents of a comment](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and store them in a variable.
2. [Destroy](http://api.jquery.com/destroy/) the HTML tag that stores the comment.
3. Use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to put the contents at the end of a div.

Comment: I'm trying to make it into threaded comments. I want the replies inside of the comment it replied to so that it will look a certain way.

Comment: If you are using Firebug, inspect the comments and move an `li` comment inside of another one to see the effect

Comment: It is **NOT** possible to move a `li` inside another `li` with CSS.

Comment: Dude...I've never mentioned using CSS. The comments in the code clearly imply me needed the use of Javascript or JQuery

Comment: I'm trying to 1. find a match for all replies who's href(excluding the hash tag) matches the id of the `li` it goes to. 2. move the entire reply(starting from the `li` node it is in) into the one it replies to wrapped in a `ul class='children`